# Where do you start with hosting the infrastructure for your infrastructure?

Tags: terraform, azure, project-management

So I'm trying to get started with the HashiCorp stack, but the question I keep asking myself, when looking at any of this DevOps infrastructure stuff, is what infrastructure should you be using to host the tools that will be managing - well - your infrastructure?

Like, for example, should I just be spinning up individual VMs to host each part of the HashiCorp stack? Should I be doing that instead using containers? Should I be managing those containers? With the same tools I'm going to be using to manage the containers managed by those containers?

Answer (score 2):

Not a stupid question, but it's lacking details. If by stack you mean Terraform, Vault, Consul etc, then you would go about provisioning machines/VMs/containers for those services likely using some form of ansible or equivalent.

It would be prudent to store those scripts in git or any other source control system.

> Like, for example, should I just be spinning up individual VMs to host each part of the HashiCorp stack? Should I be doing that instead using containers?

Personally, I find containers more flexible especially when upgrading/ testing. The only downside is you have to remember to mount a data volume into the container to persist any configuration data which would normally live beyond the lifecycle of the container.